# Upload file by git lfs correctly

Tags: github, yolo, git-lfs

I tried to upload large file ( 240mb ) to github by lfs by using

```
- git lfs install
- git init 
- git remote add origin "my repo url"
- git lfs track "*.weights" 
- git add yolov3.weights
- git commit -m "test"
- git push -u origin master
```

after uploaded i found the file content

```
versionversion https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:c49c28814dc8bcd2c48aac1c3e41c92a183cf9b282f6ca4c05f3d99393137952
size 246305388
```

And not working but the size still 240 mb

How to upload the file right or what is the wrong?

Comment: What is your question? What do you meet? What do you expect?

Comment: The file corrupted after upload, how to upload it right?

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupted"?

Comment: Iam trying to run streamlit for object detection all thing working find but when start to detect object, error appear  "error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:690: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Transpose the weights (except for convolutional) is not implemented in function 'ReadDarknetFromWeightsStream'" because the weights file (which i tried to upload) is corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  pushing the code using this command ?

```html
git push origin <branch name> --force
```

HTTPS protocol can sometimes be unreliable when it comes to pushing large files . It may break unexpectedly

why dont you try pushing the code via SSH method ?
Run these commands  below ::

```html
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "<email id>"
notepad ~/.ssh/<required key>.pub  
 // paste this public key into your github account
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add   ~/.ssh/<required_key>.pub
```

You can learn more about the ssh protocol in this  [article](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

Comment: Tried ssh and ended with error while uploading